# продолжить функцию после того как условие будет верно

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

Как мне сделать так, что бы когда условие true функция продолжила работу? там где function wait(). Пробую делать так, ошибок нет, но ничего не происходит.

```
roducts.addEventListener('click', (event) =>
{
  const element = event.target;
  
  // Проверяем, на каком элемент был произведен клик
  if (element.classList.contains('add_to_cart_button'))
  {
    // Отменяем стандартное поведение (в данном случае - переход по ссылке)
    event.preventDefault();

    let child = document.querySelector('.added_to_cart');

    let contains = element.contains(child);
    
    // Выводим информацию (href и элемент
    console.log(element.getAttribute('href'), element);
    console.log(contains);

    **function wait(){ if (contains  == false){ setTimeout(wait,100); } else { 
        const isCart = (element.textContent == 'В корзине');
    
        // Устанавливаем текст, в зависимости от текста на кнопки (Если было "В корзине" станет "В корзину" и наоборот)
        element.textContent = (isCart ? 'В корзину' : 'В корзине');
    }}; 
wait();**
  }
});
```

пробую так, так же не работает

```
    setInterval(function() {
            if (contains  == true){
                const isCart = (element.textContent == 'В корзине');
    
                // Устанавливаем текст, в зависимости от текста на кнопки (Если было "В корзине" станет "В корзину" и наоборот)
                element.textContent = (isCart ? 'В корзину' : 'В корзине');
            }
        }, 100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй

```
var t = setTimeout(function wait(){
  if(contains == true){ //твой код }
  else{
    t = setTimeout(wait, 100);
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: не работает, как и до этого

Comment: попробуй добавить перед setTimeout:
let elem = element;
а внутри используй elem

Comment: Может сделать готовый пример? Не очень понимаю

Comment: на примере твоей функции, так наверное проще будет

*function wait(elem){ if (contains  == false){ setTimeout(wait,100); } else { 
        const isCart = (elem.textContent == 'В корзине');
    
        // Устанавливаем текст, в зависимости от текста на кнопки (Если было "В корзине" станет "В корзину" и наоборот)
        elem.textContent = (isCart ? 'В корзину' : 'В корзине');
    }}; 
wait(element);**

Comment: не работает. буду через дебагер смотреть

Comment: В общем у меня ошибка, я передавал старый класс, а не новый

Comment: var t = setTimeout(function wait(){
  if(element.classList.contains('added')){ 
   const isCart = (element.textContent == 'В корзине');
    
      // Устанавливаем текст, в зависимости от текста на кнопки (Если было "В корзине" станет "В корзину" и наоборот)
      element.textContent = (isCart ? 'В корзину' : 'В корзине');
   }
  else{
    t = setTimeout(wait, 100);
  }
   }, 100);

Comment: так все работает, СПАСИБО!